# Ajax call is not working in Django?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

This is my ajax call:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#butt2").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:'{% url 'task:deletetask' %}',
                data:{'id':2 },
                type:"GET",
                success:function(text){
                    $("#task2").hide();             
                    alert(text);
            }});
        });
    });


</script>
```

This is my view function:

```
class DeleteTaskView(generic.View):
    def get(self,request):
        id = request.GET.get('id',None)
        Task.objects.get(id=id).delete()
        return JsonResponse("Task Removed")
```

This is the url:

```
url(r'user/task/delete/$',views.DeleteTaskView.as_view(),name='deletetask'),
```

If I remove the ajax call, and simply add  alert function, then it is properly working, means jquery is working, there is some problem with ajax call only. Help !

Edit: I change the url function to :

```
url : "{% url 'task:deletetask' %}",
```

Now the item is getting deleted from database but in success response hide and alert function is not working.

Comment: Have you tried printing the id to make to make sure the method is even being called and the id is being passed correctly?

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure JS reloaded.
2. Try to test url (use full link)
3. Open Broswer and press F12 ~> console and show me the error... server or client bug?

Comment: It is showing : 500 (Internal server Error). Item is getting deleted from the database, but the success  function is now working

Comment: have you done with the debug? 5xx server side ~> check the server function (put some print) to find the problem, maybe the ID or your method don't work well

Comment: And you can see the server log at CMD too, make sure you find out the error! (may be when you get object of models)

Answer (score 0):

[`JsonResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) can take - by default - only a dict parameter for data.

So you should have:

```
return JsonResponse({'text': 'Task Removed'})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to Delete the data you need to pass `post` method in ajax with csrf_token in headers.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#butt2").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:'{% url 'task:deletetask' %}',
                data:{'id':2 },
                type:"POST",
                headers: {
                  'X-CSRF-Token': {{csrf_token}}
                },
                success:function(text){
                    $("#task2").hide();             
                    alert(text);
            }});
        });
    });


</script>
```

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core import serializers

jsonObject = serializers.serialize('json', [{'text': 'Task Removed'}])
return HttpResponse(jsonObject)
```